# Cannot ssh to remote hosts on any port other than 22 from macOS

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

I recently switched the ssh listen port on my OpenWRT server running Dropbear from 22 to a random one to prevent the system log from being flooded by someone brute-forcing.

Everything is fine and I am able to connect to the server from the wan side using termux(a terminal simulator that you can install packages).

Until when I try using my MacBook to ssh into the server(under the same network with my phone, was previously able to ssh into the server when dropbear was listening on 22). The connection immediately drops and ssh throws this at me:

```
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
```

The verbose output does not really show anything helpful(and cut really abruptly may I add):

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/my_username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote.yhaoquan.top port 2123.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
```

Telnetting to port 2123 shows that I actually successfully made the connection to the server:

```
>telnet {hostname} 2123
Trying {host IP address}...
Connected to {hostname}
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-dropbear
|

��]J044��d����curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.aursa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa3chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr3chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctrhmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256nonenoneM�'�Rf
```

When I change the port back to 22 on my server, everything works again.

Does anyone know where the problem might be?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is not an answer, but might I suggest fail2ban (or something like it) instead of using a random port? :)

Comment: @negacao Hey that's a neat idea that I didn't think of, plus I can see most of the burst connections are from single ips. It will do wonder :) Will try installing that in the future if I can't get away by changing the port to something higher.

Comment: Key based ssh login also is worth looking into, imo.

Comment: @Scottmeup Definitely. I am not worried about my password being cracked because I already set up my server to do key-based auth only, if connected from wan(it's a router) but they don't seem to care that it's key-auth only and keeps on re-connecting. I just want the endless port-knocking to stop(or reduce) and bring my logs back to usable shapes:(

Comment: Which of the involved systems is running macOS?

Comment: @nohillside A macOS client is trying to connect to an OpenWRT server running dropbear